# showDatePicker's header overflow error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I'm having an issue with the date picker in flutter, when calling it from within a stepper's step:

[image]

I'm calling the showDateTimePicker from this step:

```
 new Step(
      title: new Text(
        'Día',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
      ),
      content: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100.0,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DateTimePickerFormField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                fontSize: 25.0,
              ),
              format: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm'),
              onChanged: (date) {
                if (date != null) print(date.toIso8601String());
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
      state: _currentStep >= 0 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
    ),
```

this is the error stack:

```
I/flutter ( 4388): The specific RenderFlex in question is:
I/flutter ( 4388):   RenderFlex#26a8f OVERFLOWING
I/flutter ( 4388):   creator: Column ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← _DatePickerHeader ← Column
I/flutter ( 4388):   ← SizedBox ← LayoutBuilder ← OrientationBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 4388):   parentData: offset=Offset(16.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter ( 4388):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=298.0, h=100.0)
I/flutter ( 4388):   size: Size(298.0, 100.0)
I/flutter ( 4388):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 4388):   mainAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 4388):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 4388):   crossAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 4388):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter ( 4388):   verticalDirection: down
```

Maybe someone sorted out this?

Comment: It looks like a font size of 25.0 is a bit too much. Try 23.0 or 21.0. There don't seem to be many options for layout of the date picker dialog.

Comment: fontsize here is applying to the textformfield not to the DatePicker widget, I changed it however and same results, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I think this is a bug, I changed datepicker height constant in date_picker.dart from 100 to 115 and it's now gone, for some reason it is broken.

Comment: where is your "showDatePicker" or did you gave wrong title ?

Answer (score 0):

you can also just stack flutter's datepicker and timepicker instead of using datetime_picker_formfield:

```
Future _pickDate() async {

  DateTime pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: _date,
    firstDate: _firstDate,
    lastDate: _lastDate,
  );


  TimeOfDay pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: _time,
  );


  if(pickedDate != null && pickedTime != null) {

    DateTime _newStamp = new DateTime(pickedDate.year, pickedDate.month, pickedDate.day, pickedTime.hour, pickedTime.minute);

    setState(() {
      _time = pickedTime;
      _date = pickedDate;
      _stamp = _newStamp;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Hello, before adding datetime_picker_formfield package I tried the standard one, and the I had the exact same error. Also tried to test this out in the phone to a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 (wich has plenty of screen space) and same error.

Answer (score 0):

The parts that solve the problem are SingleChildScrollView and data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(display1: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))),

````
 showDatePicker(
         context: context,
         initialDate: initDate ?? DateTime.now(),
         firstDate: firstDate ?? DateTime(1919),
         lastDate: lastDate ?? DateTime.now(),
           builder: (context, child) {
             return SingleChildScrollView(
               child: Theme(

                 isMaterialAppTheme: true,
                 data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(display1: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))),

                   child: child
                 ),
               );
           });```
````

Comment: Can you please consider adding some explanation in your answer, describing which parts solve the original question and how?